# Is there any way to suppress Duplicate Column Validation in Hibernate 5?

Tags: hibernate

Sample Query :

`SELECT txrefno,txrefno from FTDMASTER`

Exception: Caused by:

> org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException:
>   Encountered a duplicated sql alias [TXREFNO] during auto-discovery of
>   a native-sql query

Is there any way to suppress Duplicate Column Validation in Hibernate 5?

Comment: why do you need the same column twice?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an alias for the second column:

```
SELECT txrefno, txrefno as txrefno2 from FTDMASTER
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, problem in my scenario is i cant make any changes in the query, since it will be generated in runtime . So changing query wont work.

Comment: Can you update the question with your code showing how the query is generated / used?